# How to make CSS Sprites align vertically for Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, sprite

I am using two CSS Sprites (each in their own div) to display an Android and Apple logo on my homepage. It looks fine when on a laptop, however, it does not align correctly (in the center) when viewed on a smaller device i.e. mobile device/small browser.

Could anyone lend a hand and help me get the Sprites to align vertically when viewed on mobile?

Here's what it looks like in full screen and mobile/small browser:

**Fullscreen (working): **

[image]

**Mobile (no working): **

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="main-container">

    <div class="left-image">
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul class="group">
          <li class="nav-android"><a href="#">Android</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="right-image">
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul class="group">
          <li class="nav-ios"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left: 20%;
}

.site-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  text-indent: 9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-android a {
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  background-image: url(../images/android.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.nav-ios a {
  float: left;
  left: -50%;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  background-image: url(../images/apple.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .nav-android a,
  .nav-ios a,
  {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
```

Comment: are you sure it's a sprite? I see 2 different image ... maybe you simply need `background-size:cover`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The 2 images are added using CSS Sprites so that I can add a hover effect later. There's no <img> tag in the html.

Comment: can you create a snippet or fiddle with your original images ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for css.

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px)
{
    .nav-android a, .nav-ios a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        background-size: 128px 128px;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Maybe you need to add this to head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0"/>
```

```css
 ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 
 .group { margin-top: 10%; text-align: center; }
 .group li { display: inline-block; }
 .group li a { display: block; width: 256px; height: 256px; font-size: 0; }

 .nav-android a {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url(android.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: green;
 }

 .nav-ios a {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url(apple.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: grey;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <ul class="group">
      <li class="nav-android"><a href="#">Android</a></li>
      <li class="nav-ios"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks! This worked perfectly. I appreciate your help :)